# How to check if a submit button has been clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I am new to javascript language,and i couldnt find a javascript approach for this php statement:

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
//more if statements
} else { echo 'Error'; }
```

In other words,i want to make a form validation in javascript to check if a submit button has been pressed.

Comment: Just use the click event.

Comment: Use the `submit` handler for the form element.

Comment: call a function when the submit button is clicked like this `<input type="submit" value="submit" onlcick=your_function()>`, and in that function do ur validation

Comment: I'll write an use case for who else is wondering about why this can be useful, think of a AJAX filter form  with listing which has pagination below, if the filters are changed, users will click the filter button, when the pagination is clicked, the hidden input containing the page updated and the form is submitted again by script, and if you want to differentiate this, you may want to use this question's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.onclick`:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/y6gmhh6j/)

#### HTML:

```
<input type="submit" />
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var submit = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
submit.onclick = function() {
    alert("Button pressed!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you don't necessarily "check if the submit button has been pressed", you respond to the submit button's events.  For example, the `form` has a `submit` event:

```
function someHandlerFunction() {
    // respond to the form submit event here
}

var form = document.getElementById('theFormId');
form.addEventListener("submit", someHandlerFunction);
```

Or you can respond to the `click` event of the button itself:

```
var button = document.getElementById('theButtonId');
button.addEventListener("click", someHandlerFunction);
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine and others, because a form can be submit on more ways as pressing a button.

Comment: sorry,i've been off for few days,but i've came back and i have few question if i may, i dont understand what's the "click" from button.addeventlistener ....

Comment: @PetruLebada: It's the event being handled.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an onclick event to the submit button. So when the button in the form is pressed, you run a  function.
Basically it can look like this:

```js
function save(){
   alert(document.getElementById("myInput").value);
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="test">
<button onclick="save()">Save!</button>
```